# Read a file with repeating batches Using Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

We have as clob object in the database which has repeating batches which is identified by the record marker '5'. Each '5' type record has a list of transaction record which have record marker as '6'. I am thinking of using Spring Batch to read the clob object.

I am aware Matching Pattern Parser, which Spring batch provide. I need help on how to structure the batch job so that it can read the the record type 5 & record type 6 in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you need a custom item reader for this kind of input. You can use the `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` to look ahead if the upcoming item is of type 5 and add the following transactions to the clob. Since a logical item spans multiple physical lines, you can follow the same idea as these examples:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline-order-job

Hope this helps.